# Can I use a continuous form in this case

Tags: continuous

I would like to say that since we have been here (about one month now) it keeps raining a little but **every day**

Can I use the continuous form

It has been raining a little since we have been here

Comment: I don't think it's ungrammatical, but it's very ambiguous and awkward.  "A little" isn't clear.  Is it continuous light rain, intermittent rain, a few minutes of downpour a few times a day?  The answers provide clearer ways to say it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one out of many possible answers about how to express the idea:

> It's been raining continuously since we got here. Usually it's just a light rain, a drizzle.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is meant by "a little".

> It has been raining on and off since we arrived.
>
> It has been raining lightly ever since we arrived.

The use of **ever** in the second example implies that the rain has been continuous.